# How to extract value of a key from an object of arrays in python

Tags: python, json, for-loop

This might be a real noob question.

Thanks for helping.

I am receiving a json payload with the below structure

```
 {
    "response": true,
    "error": null,
    "msg": null,
    "data": {
        "slots": {
            "04/26/2022": [
                {
                    "0": 1650958200000,
                    "1": 19800,
                    "3": "1:00 PM",
                    "4": "26/Apr/2022 13:00 IST"
                },
                {
                    "0": 1650960000000,
                    "1": 19800,
                    "3": "1:30 PM",
                    "4": "26/Apr/2022 13:30 IST"
                },
                {
                    "0": 1650963600000,
                    "1": 19800,
                    "3": "2:30 PM",
                    "4": "26/Apr/2022 14:30 IST"
                },
                {
                    "0": 1650965400000,
                    "1": 19800,
                    "3": "3:00 PM",
                    "4": "26/Apr/2022 15:00 IST"
                },
                {
                    "0": 1650967200000,
                    "1": 19800,
                    "3": "3:30 PM",
                    "4": "26/Apr/2022 15:30 IST"
                }
            ],
            "04/24/2022": [],
            "04/25/2022": [],
            "04/23/2022": []
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a new object with an array of the values of "0". Output should be

```
{
 "slots": [
          1650958200000,
          1650960000000,
          1650963600000,
          1650965400000,
          1650967200000
          ]
}
```

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to lose the date information? Looks like `slots` contains date keys and arrays of dictionaries. If you just take the value at the `"0"` key, you'll lose the 'date' which that element came from.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any Python code to go along with this?

Comment: please provide the source code you have and what is the bug you are facing in your code.

Comment: @ddejohn yeah the "0" value is the unix timestamp, so once I have that, it's more than enough.

Comment: i'm currently trying to loop the items and get the "0" key 

with 

`   for slots in res_slots['data']['slots']:
               slots.split(",")
               print(slots[0])`

however i this as the output
`1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a straight-forward approach:

```py
slots = payload["data"]["slots"]  # Assumes payload has been converted from JSON to Python

slots_obj = {"slots": [d["0"] for _, lst in slots.items() for d in lst]}
```

Output:

```py
{'slots': [1650958200000,
           1650960000000,
           1650963600000,
           1650965400000,
           1650967200000,
           16539137693178]}
```

If you haven't already, use `json.loads` to convert the JSON to a Python dictionary:

```py
import json

payload = json.loads(payload)
```

The solution above uses what's known as a list comprehension. It is equivalent to a `for` loop, which may be easier to understand:

```py
timestamps = []  # Initialize an empty list to accumulate the Unix timestamps

# Iterate over each date, array pair in the slots dictionary using slots.items()
for _, slot_array in slots.items():
    # Iterate over each inner dictionary
    for slot_dict in slot_array:
        # Grab the value at the "0" and append it to the timestamps accumulator
        timestamps.append(slot_dict["0"])

# Finally create the new object, a dictionary with one key, "slots"
slots_obj = {"slots": timestamps}
```

Comment: See my edit for an explanation. My solution uses a very common pattern called a "list comprehension".

Comment: Is there another way to do this other than using a for loop? I have the same requirement, but I'd need to loop over more than 100000 dicts.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `json` module as in `ddejohn`'s approach will be more efficient than the approach shown here. However, I thought it would be useful for you to see other ways of obtaining your desired output.

If the above is a string, say, `s`, you can use `findall()` from the `re` module to extract those numbers.

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'(?<="0": )\d+(?=,)')
d = {'slots': [int(x) for x in p.findall(s)]}

print(d)
```

Output

```
{'slots': [1650958200000,
           1650960000000,
           1650963600000,
           1650965400000,
           1650967200000]}
```

The regular expression `r'(?<="0": )\d+(?=,)'` matches one or more digits that are preceded by `"0":`  and that are followed by a `,`. `findall(s)` returns all (nonoverlapping) matches of this expression in the string `s` as a list of strings. In particuar, `p.findall(s)` returns the list

```
['1650958200000',
 '1650960000000',
 '1650963600000',
 '1650965400000',
 '1650967200000']
```

`[int(x) for x in p.findall(s)]` creates a new list formed by taking each element of the list returned by `p.findall(s)` and converting it into an integer.

**Timings**

---

Using the `json` module as in `ddejohn`'s approach will be more efficient.

```
# ddejohn
6.14 µs ± 41 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

# oda
14.6 µs ± 76.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Why would OP do this when `json` exists and OP can treat the payload as a dictionary over which iteration and keyed access is vastly more efficient?

Comment: @ddejohn I ran both solutions through `%%timeit` with IPython and added the timings to make it clear that the `json` approach is better.

Answer (score 0):

I did the next program, i hope that will be useful to you.

But you should have on mind that you will probably lose important information

The explanation of how It's works is in the program

```
import json

dicc={}

# We open the file
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.JSONDecoder().decode(f.read())

    # We get the data
    slots=data['data']['slots']

    # We travel to the slots and we get the key
    for slot in slots:

        # We get the data and put them in the dictionary
        for key in slots[slot]:

            # If slots key is not created, we create it
            if "slots" not in dicc:

                # We create the list that will contain the data
                dicc["slots"]=[]

            #We add the data to the list in the dictionary
            dicc["slots"].append(key['0'])

new_json=json.dumps(dicc)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).